# VBA: Function that will find the sheet name with the highest number of all the sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

Assume there is a workbook with seven sheets, and the sheet names are as follows:

"Terms"

"Revolvers"

"15"

"22"

"55"

"59"

"146"

I need VBA code that will identify the highest numbered sheet name of any sheet in the whole workbook.  In this example, it should identify 146 as the highest number.  Then the code should create a new sheet, with a sheet name that is one integer higher than the previous sheet name.  In this example, the new sheet would be created and then named "147".  Below is my code, I just need to replace "tab name + 1" with the proper function:

```
Sub AddSheet()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim strName As String: strName = "tab name + 1"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
With ws
    .Name = strName
End With

End Sub
```

**Edit Based on BigBen's Answer Below**

```
Sub AddSheet()


Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim strName As String: strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
With ws
    .Name = strName
End With

End Sub

Function MaxSheetNumber(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Dim i As Long
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
            If CLng(ws.Name) > i Then
                i = CLng(ws.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MaxSheetNumber = i
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a function like this:

```
Function MaxSheetNumber(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Dim i As Long
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
            If CLng(ws.Name) > i Then
                i = CLng(ws.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MaxSheetNumber = i
End Function
```

This can be easily modified to return a default value, say `1`, if no numbered sheets exist in the workbook (although it will currently return `0` and that might be what you want, if you plan to add `1` for the new tab).

In your code:

```
strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply.  When I try to run this code I recieve the error "Compile error" unexpected array" and the MaxSheetNumber is highlighted. I declared MaxSheetNumber as Long

Comment: You shouldn't have declared anything. Dump the entire function into the module, and then change `strName = "tab name + 1"` to `strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see the updated edit below the bold font in my original question.  Really appreciate the help

Comment: See my comment. `Function...End Function` is a new block and should be after `End Sub`.

Comment: Ok, I have placed Function... End Function after End Sub and it created a new sheet, but the sheet name is "False".  Do you have any trouble shoot ideas?  I'll update my edit to show the current order

Comment: Change `strName = strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)` to just `strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)`. You've got an extra `strName =`.

Comment: Lol thank you, I'm an idiot.  It works now. Thank you so much for you patience